# bundle invalid - application executable contains embedded INFO PLIST section

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

[image]

I'm trying to submit my app in Xcode with the Archive tool, and when I click validate or distribute, I get this error. Anyone know why it's happening?? I have tried messing with my Info.plist file a lot but nothing seems to help!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had accidentally thrown in this configuration for my Other Linking Flags:

```
-sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist $(INFOPLIST_FILE)
```

I must have used it to debug something else and left it there by accident. According to [this web post](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/2083/the-power-of-plist), it's for embedding (hiding) your Info.plist in your binary (which I guess isn't allowed on iOS / anymore?)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your targets built settings are set like this:

[image]